# Nuke: Write Node two paths that save

Tags: python, nuke

For Nuke I would like to have a write node that saves two of the same image sequences to differnet locations.

The locations will be a Version and a Publish.  I have it working as an autowrite node currenlty but can't get the second path to render and save?

Here's a snip but I'm not sure how to have it actually render and save the image?  It only renders the default path of the write node.  Also the idea is to have nuke only render once but save two images.

```
w.addKnob(nuke.File_Knob('pubOutput', 'Publish Output'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if the image formats are the same, you could do it with a shutil.copy() command after each frame, to the destination you want.

If you want the formats to be different, you can easily add another write node alongside the first one with the settings you choose. Nuke can render any number of write nodes at once, and if they are connected to the same dot, you shouldn't experience much of a slowdown.

Comment: It's been a while but thank you for your help.   I've chosen to do the two write node verison and I am currently writing the Auto "Publish" node.    I'm stuck atm as it doesn't reconnect to and existing "MN_AutoWrite_PUBLISH" write node.  It only works on new create MN_AutoWrite_PUBLISH write nodes.  Is there anything particular that needs to be included - I feel I'm missing something fundamental.  I can send u the code.

Comment: do I need to add something to the init.py file?

Comment: hmmm, maybe time for a new detailed question?